# Strange merge behavior in Azure DevOps using Git

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request

The business recently planned to test two separate features in the same sprint, but weren't sure if both of them were going to be deployed. Our solution was to create two feature branches off of Develop, one for each feature, and a third branch off of develop ("the Hybrid Branch") into which those feature branches could be merged. We would only deploy to DEV and QA from the Hybrid Branch, allowing dev and QA to test both features. If one of them was pulled back, the individual feature branch would be merged to develop and deployed without the other.

But we've encountered some strange behavior with one of the feature branches when merging into the hybrid branch.

**When creating a pull request, Azure DevOps merges every change from the date that the feature branch was created.** It's as if the branch doesn't get rebased properly after a push or merge or what-have-you.

For the other feature branch, it pulls only the set of commits pushed since the last merge. This is how we expect it to work.

This makes reviews of the pull request difficult, as it's difficult to isolate the specific changes for the PR. It also means that resolved conflicts have to be re-resolved for every PR, and the PR acts like previously added or removed files need to be added or removed again.

What could be causing this and how do we resolve it?

Comment: Similar thing happens when I merge (using rebase) a PR branch and then continue working on that branch and create another PR. In this case, merging back the main branch (develop in your case) should help: `git merge origin/develop`. You might have to resolve some conflicts though.

Comment: I didn't find this point very clear: `It's as if the branch doesn't get rebased properly after a push or merge or what-have-you.` where exactly are you rebasing? If you have rebased a branch back to its origin on master, then it will inevitably have to be merged with everything in master and in the other branch, because every commit has been rewritten with a new ID. They don't necessarily conflict, but they are still different commits. Appearing as changes relative to master would be expected. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @TomW "Rebase" was probably not the right term to use. Theoretically, Git uses some "last merged commit pointer" to track the last merge between the two branches. Subsequent merges would only include commits made after that "last merged commit pointer." That doesn't seem to be getting updated on the one feature branch, but it does on the other. So we experience radically different behavior between two feature branches merging into the same hybrid branch.

Comment: Are you sure that commits that are supposed to be the same on both have indeed the same hashes? And the same hashes on the "hybrid" branch? Are you sure nothing has been rebased? For example maybe someone have rebased some commits when merging to the hybrid branch? Maybe you used merge with --squash?

Comment: @TuanPham We do typically squash our merges. However, we do the same thing on both branches, and the other branch works just fine. I would think that if squashing was the issue, we'd run into it on the other branch as well.

Comment: @MikeHofer I still think it's because of squashing.  The way git works isn't by tracking some "last merged commit pointer". Every time you merge branches, git looks for any commits that are present on one branch and not present on another. It does it by comparing hashes. So if you merge with squash, then those commits are merged to another branch with different hashes, so the next merge will show them as new commits again.

Maybe the other branch was rebased to the first? You can check hashes of commits to make sure that they are indeed different on both branches.

Comment: @TuanPham Please move your last comment to an answer, so you can claim the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because of squashing. The way git works isn't by tracking a "last merged commit pointer". Every time you merge branches, git looks for any commits that are present on one branch and not present on another. It does it by comparing hashes. So if you merge with squash, then those commits are merged to another branch with different hashes, so the next merge will show them as new commits again.

Regarding one branch working properly, maybe the other branch was rebased to the first? You can check hashes of commits to make sure that they are indeed different on both branches